# Generic intersection results in "'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type" error

Tags: typescript

Generic conditionals have their evaluation deferred, so I am attempting to use an intersection to hint to the compiler my desired type:

```
type ArgType<T> = T & (T extends MyType ? ({
    myArg?: MyInterface<T>
    })
  : never)
```

However, when I try to invoke a function that access an argument typed to the above, I am getting this error:

> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ myArg: this; }'

Full code:

```
type MyType = 'foo';

interface MyInterface<T extends MyType> {
    myField: T;
}

type ArgType<T> = T & (T extends MyType ? ({
    myArg?: MyInterface<T>
    })
  : never)

function myFunc<T>(arg: ArgType<T>) {
    return arg;
}

class MyClass<T extends MyType> implements MyInterface<T> {
    constructor(readonly myField: T) {}
    invoke() {
        const result = myFunc({
            myArg: this
        });
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oHIBmB7LaDcAUAQJYB2wEAThgIYDG0cAkuVbQwDzxQQAeFpACYBnWAiQA+KAG8CUeVAC2IAGLEIAG0EAuKPEIBfIqEhQAgpQDmiSFympuAMigAKbnwEixN6AH5XsgpKIBaWvrrMrNT0EHZyCgYAlPG6pBAAblTJBBgArqR0wMRYpMEq+XR2LjRWuqE+doky8fKUEMC5lKU1loZEdBo0wqJwAMKDw1w8-BBCI+KQUsSKYBoQirPA8ywU0ZzwUoEKdCXCwJS5hViULm00giUaIGXqWrrwTdJGQWTpWADWEBcnxaQSgJ1IZygbWEuQ0wCgqGU5QKLiOYLBylCumAAAtiMJQUEkoRiQQDEA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type MyType = 'foo';

interface MyInterface<T extends MyType> {
    myField: T;
}

type ArgType<T> = T extends MyType ? {
    myArg?: MyInterface<T>;
} : never;

function myFunc<T>(arg: ArgType<T>) {
    return arg;
}

class MyClass<T extends MyType> implements MyInterface<T> {
    constructor(readonly myField: T) {}
    invoke() {
        const result = myFunc<MyType>({
            myArg: this
        });
    }
}
```